# PDFView printWithInfo:autoRotate: fails

Tags: objective-c, printing, pdfview

I'm trying to print a PDFDocument that I am constructing from a series of images. In case it matters, I'm doing all of this from within a Mozilla plugin.

I create the PDFDocument, and put it into a PDFView, then I call

```
[printView printWithInfo: [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo] autoRotate: YES];
```

The print dialog comes up (as a separate window, instead of panel. I assume that that comes from being inside a mozilla window, so I wasn't too worried about it. The dialog shows my document, and I can page through it correctly, and everything looks good.

However, when I hit "Print" the dropdown with "Layout" etc becomes empty, and the view under that becomes empty. The window doesn't disappear, and the document doesn't print. Hitting Cancel does exactly the same thing. The only thing I can do then is force-quit Mozillla.

I based the program off of [PDFKitLinker2](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/PDFKitLinker2/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003594) from the apple dev site, and that program works. But I can't see any significant differences between it and my version.

Any suggestions on where to look?

thanks.

EDIT: Yes, I know that this is pretty much an exact duplicate of [Printing Off-screen PDFViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058501/printing-off-screen-pdfviews) but that never got a sufficient answer...  (And I didn't notice it until just now...)

Comment: See similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080344/cocoa-osx-pdfview-nsprintoperation-printpanel-not-showing-page-preview/43932633#43932633 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058501/printing-off-screen-pdfviews/43932657#43932657

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you have a memory management issue here. Have you checked the console log to see if there's an exception being thrown? How are you creating your `PDFView`?

But why not do it the way [WebKit](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebKit/mac/WebView/WebPDFView.mm#L71) does it?

Specifically, declare a category on `PDFDocument`

```
@interface PDFDocument (PDFSecretsIKnowViaWebKit)
- (NSPrintOperation *)getPrintOperationForPrintInfo:(NSPrintInfo *)printInfo autoRotate:(BOOL)doRotate;
@end
```

Then when you want to print your `PDFDocument` simply get an `NSPrintOperation` from it and run it.

```
NSPrintOperation *op = [myPDFDoc getPrintOperationForPrintInfo:info autoRotate:YES];
[op runOperation];
// [op runOperationModalForWindow:delegate:didRunSelector:contextInfo:] if you have a window to attach it to
```

Comment: And there are no messages in the console log after I hit the "print" button.

Comment: Ok, so yet ANOTHER un-documented method that I need to use... *sigh* Well, at least it works.

Comment: I'd definitely encourage you to file a bug (http://bugreport.apple.com) asking for that behavior to be documented. I'm sure it'll be marked as a dup but it does serve as a kind of vote for the feature.

Comment: Here's an all caps: THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me too. I've verified that getPrintOperationForPrintInfo:autoRotate: exists and appears to work correctly on 10.4, 10.5 and 10.6.