# How do I print a PDF File from OSX using Swift and PDFKit

Tags: macos, pdf, swift3

I have a PDF file that I would like to spool to the printer directly using Swift and PDFKit. I load the document using PDFDocument and then create a PDFView and print the view. The print panel appears with the correct document and all the correct printer information, but the print button does nothing. How do I get the document to print?

Here is my code extract:

```
let pdfDoc = PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: pdfPath))
let pdfView = PDFView()
pdfView.document = pdfDoc
pdfView.print(with: printInfo, autoRotate: false)
```

Comment: Did you check the connection with the printer?

Comment: Hi. This had nothing to do with the printer or the document. The problem was that the PDFView was not associated with any window. I found the solution in swift in the following post [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058501/printing-off-screen-pdfviews